# Can't get my custom styling to be used by WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to apply custom styling for one table to a wordpress theme I am using, but I can't seem to get the table to use my custom styling. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong that I am missing?

Here is the form code with my edit class:

```
<table class="edit"><tr><td><form action="" method="post"><button type="submit"
class="link"><span>Form Approve</span>   </button></form>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<form action=""
method="post"><button type="submit" class="link"><span>Form Delete</span></button></form>
</td></tr></table>


//Wordpress theme style 

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin-bottom: 15px; 
}

table th {
background:#eee;
border: 1px solid #fff;
padding: 10px; 
}

table tr {
background:#f5f5f5;
}

table td {
border: 1px solid #fff;
padding: 10px; 
}



//MY CUSTOM STYLING

.edit table {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin-bottom: 2px; 
}

.edit table th {
background:#eee;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
padding: 0px; 
}

.edit table tr {
background:#ffffff;
}

.edit table td {
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
padding: 2px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.edit table` does not exist (that would be a table inside of another element that has a class of "edit"), instead you should use `.edit` or `table.edit`. Example:

```
.edit {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin-bottom: 15px; 
}

.edit th {
background:#eee;
border: 1px solid #fff;
padding: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I cant really tell you whats wrong besides that fact that your wordpress template styling  is the exact same as your custom styling.

I don't think you really need the edit class you can just overide the styles with out it and also .edit would go after table so it would look something like this

```
table.edit {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin-bottom: 15px; 
}
```